# Function parameters: intedeterminately sequenced or unsequenced?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, function-parameter, sequence-points

On [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) I see the following text:

> In a function call, value computations and side effects of the initialization of every parameter are indeterminately sequenced with respect to value computations and side effects of any other parameter.

Hovewer, I wasn't able to find any confirmation of this in C++17 standard.

Function parameters, as subexpressions, should comply with [intro.execution.17]:

> Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual
>   expressions are unsequenced. [ Note: In an expression that is evaluated more than once during the execution
>   of a program, unsequenced and indeterminately sequenced evaluations of its subexpressions need not be
>   performed consistently in different evaluations. — end note ] The value computations of the operands of
>   an operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator. If a side effect on a
>   memory location (4.4) is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same memory location or a
>   value computation using the value of any object in the same memory location, and they are not potentially
>   concurrent (4.7), the behavior is undefined. [ Note: The next section imposes similar, but more complex
>   restrictions on potentially concurrent computations. — end note ]

Which means, that function parameters calculation should be unsequenced unless it's prohibited by any other points in the standard. I tried to find a substring "indeterminately" in the standard text, and none of 10 occurrences look relevant to function call arguments.

So, the question is: are the function parameters unsequenced or indeterminately sequenced in C++17?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [**[expr.call]/5**](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#8) The *postfix-expression* is sequenced before each expression in the *expression-list* and any default argument. The initialization of a parameter, including every associated value computation and side effect, is **indeterminately sequenced** with respect to that of any other parameter.

Emphasis mine.